# http4s configuration from spring cloud config server

Tags: scala, spring-cloud-config-server, http4s

We have a rest microservice developed using scala http4s. We want to externalize configuration for this microservice like we do in spring boot ecosystem.

Can this be done in Scala Http4s where they can refer a spring cloud config server? Is there any other to do in Scala?

Comment: This is not related to Scala but really to http4s specifically.

Comment: Agree, but is there any code-snippet for the same?